# React Native and preferred fonts for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

Using React Native is it possible to select a preferred font with a text style type on iOS?

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifont/1619030-preferredfontfortextstyle

I use this myself for my native apps but I don't see a way to access this functionality from a React Native app.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking; I've never heard the term "preferred font" for React Native.  Are you asking how to change the font family on a component?  React Native has both built-in font families and allows custom fonts to be installed.  Here's a list of built-in font families: https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-fonts

Comment: On iOS the best way to use fonts is through `+preferredFontForTextStyle` because they scale with your font settings in your accessibility settings. I don't understand how to handle this in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

React Native is more similar to HTML.  You can set the font of a component using the `fontFamily` attribute in the style property.  If you want the font to scale (which it does by default) with the accessibility settings, you set the `allowFontScaling` of the Text element.

So, if you want to display a piece of text in Arial (I don't know if that's actually a font that is available on iOS), you would do this:

```
<Text 
    allowFontScaling={true}
    style={{ fontFamily: 'Arial' }}
>
    My incredibly well written and scalable prose
</Text>
```